# How do I configure nginx on RHEL to recognize root SSL certificates of external sites?

Tags: nginx, ssl-certificate

**Setup**: I have a nginx reverse proxy that is a load balancer for ASP.NET applications.

The problem is when ASP.NET application tries to access an external application, the SSL handshake fails. I think the SSL/TLS connection exists between the external server and the nginx reverse proxy. So, basically, the SSL certificate of the external website is not recognized by the nginx reverse proxy.

How do I configure the nginx on RHEL to recognize the server certificate? Is it a nginx configuration or does it just use client certificates installed on RHEL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In most configurations the requests originating from the .Net application servers are routed independently and that reverse proxy never comes into play...

I would investigate how a web service request would be routed from the application server. I.e. First

- Can the external host be resolved
- is there a default gateway and does that one grant access to the Internet
- is there a firewall blocking outgoing requests.
- Do you need to use a HTTP proxy?

Only when there are no network connectivity issues start checking SSL problems.
If the remote requests used to work in the past, it may be that the remote site has upgraded security after the poodle protocol vulnerability and SSLv3 is disabled in favor of TLS. And your application does not support that.